# How to handle dialog box through selenium with python?

Tags: selenium

I am new in Selenium automation. Could you please explain me how to use this (if one exists) tag? It would be really helpful if you can give example.

The scenario where I am facing problem is: there is a save button, if we click on it a dialog box pops up. I need to enter some text in two text boxes and press save/cancel button on the same dialog. I am using Selenium as a tool and Python as a scripting language. Any help on this will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
sel.click("idOfSaveButton")
sel.wait_for_pop_up("popupWindowName", "30000")
sel.select_window("name=popupWindowName")
sel.type("idOfTextBox1", "someText")
sel.type("idOfTextBox2", "someText")
sel.click("idOfCloseButton")
sel.select_window("null")
```

You can also select the popup window using `title=`.

Comment: If the dialog box is native application like in most of the cases then this will not work

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for the confirm box, then switch to it and do whatever you want. I asked familiar question before and the answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003003/check-if-any-alert-exists-using-selenium-with-python?answertab=active#tab-top). Hope it helps.