# Check if any alert exists using selenium with python

Tags: python, selenium, testing, alert, window-handles

I'm trying to write a test with selenium in python language for a web page that manages users. In this page someone can add role for users and if a role exists while adding it, an alert raises. I don't know if the alert is a javascript alert or an element of the web page. I want to automatically check the existence of the alert, because checking for the role in the list wastes time and has an enormous load. I tried this:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("url")
browser.find_the_element_by_id("add_button").click()
try:
    alert = browser.switch_to_alert()
    alert.accept()
    print "alert accepted"
except:
    print "no alert"
```

But it didn't work and I got the "UnexpectedAlertPresentException".
I also tried this:

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("url")
browser.find_the_element_by_id("add_button").click()
s = set(browser.window_handles)
s.remove(browser.current_window_handle)
browser.switch_to_window(s.pop())
```

But I got the same exception.
Additionally, I tried to access the alert with firebug to check if I can get access with its properties, but right click was disabled.
I need a solution very quickly, even in other languages. I can understand the approach anyway.
I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried a short delay between the click and the switch_to_alert?

Comment: not yet, thank you for this suggestion @Richard. I think I can use the code that A.R. gave me

Comment: @Richard must be there a delay between the  `switch_to_alert()` to  `accept()` ? Otherwise there could be a problem, you think ?

Comment: @begueradj, I think @Richard meant I should put a delay between `click()` on the element and `switch_to_alert()`.

Comment: Just turn it off :D self.execute_script('window.alert = function(){};')

Answer (score 122, accepted):

What I do is to set a conditional delay with WebDriverWait just before the point I expect to see the alert, then switch to it, like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("url")
browser.find_element_by_id("add_button").click()

try:
    WebDriverWait(browser, 3).until(EC.alert_is_present(),
                                   'Timed out waiting for PA creation ' +
                                   'confirmation popup to appear.')

    alert = browser.switch_to.alert
    alert.accept()
    print("alert accepted")
except TimeoutException:
    print("no alert")
```

`WebDriverWait(browser,`**3**`)` will wait for at least 3 seconds for a supported alert to appear.

Comment: thank you @A.R.
It completely worked for me. I've been stuck into this problem for like 10 hours.

Comment: How is it possible to detect all the alerts that can exist on a webpage (automatic popup, without clicking on a button)?

Comment: Just a small piece of info- switch_to_alert( ) is now deprecated and has been replaced with switch_to.alert

Comment: "timeout" would be a nice additional arg on `switch_to_alert()`

Comment: That's quite good. On my owns i use always a while to detect more than 1 alerts in the same call, because some of them have one at entry and one at exit. The best if you call that function at start and the end, as a wrapper for alerts.. Like that `while EC.alert_is_present: time.sleep(2) # wait a bit for more alerts(); driver.switch_to.alert.accept()`

Comment: how to check if alert exists or not.if exist do something else do something

Comment: ```browser.switch_to.alert()``` should be ```browser.switch_to.alert``` -- (no parentheses after 'alert'

Comment: @user3522371 I have the same problem. I have noticed that the string after EC.alert_is_present() doesn't work. So I used the following code.   `try: 
    WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(EC.alert_is_present())
    alert = driver.switch_to.alert
    if alert.text == "alert 1": ... if alert.text == "alert 2": ...`

Comment: Does this work on linux with headless ChromeOptions?

Answer (score 13):

I know this is a too late answer and you have solved this question years ago, but I still want to post my analysis and findings for possible future readers' reference.

I am working on a Django website development project, and currently there is a bug that once a particular web page is opened, an error message box is popped up. My environment is:

- Django 1.8
- Python 2.7
- Selenium 2.46.0

I read the document [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException) about the "UnexpectedAlertPresentException", and it says:

> Thrown when an unexpected alert is appeared.
>
> Usually raised when when an expected modal is blocking webdriver form executing any more commands.

I tested in my project and my findings are:

- When the alert box is up, the `find_element_by_X` methods can succeed.
- The click() or send_keys() will fail with the "UnexpectedAlertPresentException".

Therefore, I think the `try...catch` block doesn't work because the "UnexpectedAlertPresentException" is thrown in the line of

```
browser.find_the_element_by_id("add_button").click()
```

This also means that the alert box may appear as soon as the web page is opened by this line:

```
browser.get("url")
```

In other words, there might be a problem hidden deeper behind that caused the alert box up as soon as the page is opened. You may need to fix that problem first.

Another thing is: Assuming the alert box showed up ***after*** this line:

```
browser.find_the_element_by_id("add_button").click()
```

Then the `alert = browser.switch_to_alert()` should work well with no exception thrown, which contradicts to what you describe here. This also made me think that the problem is as early as the `browser.get("url")` line.

I'm not very sure how the selected solution helped you solve the problem because my analysis shows the problem lies in a different place. **Anyway, I am not asking for reselecting the accepted solution. I just want to share my thoughts for future readers.** Apologize in case that I overlooked or misunderstood something in this question which caused my analysis to be wrong (and which wastes your time reading this :-).

Comment: Thanks a lot for contributing to the community in this generous way.

Answer (score 2):

In java we do it like this

```
WebDriverWait wait3 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 7000);
wait3.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
driver.switchTo().alert().accept();
```

It will implicitly wait for alert if alert is not present it will throw 'Alert is not present Exceptio' which we can catch and move ahead.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you @Abhishek Singh. I did the same in python and it was the solution.

Answer (score 2):

### Try this short solution using explicit wait method.

```
try:
    wait.until(EC.alert_is_present())
    driver.switch_to.alert.accept()
    print("Alert accepted")
except:
    print("no Alert found")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
alert = self.driver.switch_to.alert
    if alert.is_displayed():
        alert.accept()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While answers are welcome in general, please consider adding context to your code so that others understand your solution.

Comment: ``` if alert.is_displayed():
AttributeError: 'Alert' object has no attribute 'is_displayed'```