# JS AlertBox throwing JavaScript Error: "e is null

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, selenium

I am having a problem with a JS Alert box, it was suppose to be working but all of sudden this popped up.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: [JavaScript Error: "e is null" {file: "file:///var/folders/8t/n1tmxt2s4cjc_g3hc_4sm6_x3_m7_l/T/tmpTmBrlm/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command-processor.js" line: 7854}] ...
```

I dont know if you guys can help me out. It's python selenium code and browser is Firefox 32 to 34.

My Code is under

```
def testArticleDekExternalLinksTest(self):
        """Practitest id :305"""
        addArticlePage = AP.AddArticlePage(self.driver,"m.php?t=articles") 
        addArticlePage.getRandomEditorialArticle()
        keys = "https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl"
        addArticlePage.clickDekExternalLinks()

        alert = self.driver.switch_to.alert
        print alert
        alert.send_keys(keys)
        alert.accept()
        self.assertTrue(addArticlePage.save(), "cannot save an Article")
        self.driver.refresh()
        addArticlePage.clickHtmlView(0)
        time.sleep(2)
        assert keys in addArticlePage.getDekContentUrlStripped()

        addArticlePage.loadUrl(addArticlePage.getPreviewUrl())
        articlePage = ArticlePage.ArticlePage(self.driver)
```

If i try to print the Alert out I can see the Alert Object even adding timing doesn't helps and weirdest part is it was working before and not working now.. Selenium version is 2.45.0

Comment: Please show us how you are handling this from your code

Comment: What are `print alert 
        alert.send_keys(keys)` lines doing?

Comment: @Saifur it prints out the alert

<selenium.webdriver.common.alert.Alert object at 0x10b467350>

Comment: `alert.send_keys(keys)` ? I would suggest to remove those two lines and try

Comment: let me give it a shot

Comment: @Saifur I tried without sending keys... but it gives the same issue...

Answer (score 1):

Ok. It seems like a wait issue to me. try this with [explicit wait](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) and give the alert sometime to exist

```
def testArticleDekExternalLinksTest(self):
        """Practitest id :305"""
        addArticlePage = AP.AddArticlePage(self.driver,"m.php?t=articles") 
        addArticlePage.getRandomEditorialArticle()
        keys = "https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl"
        addArticlePage.clickDekExternalLinks()

        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.alert_is_present())
        alert = self.driver.switch_to.alert
        print alert
        alert.send_keys(keys)
        alert.accept()
        self.assertTrue(addArticlePage.save(), "cannot save an Article")
        self.driver.refresh()
        addArticlePage.clickHtmlView(0)
        time.sleep(2)
        assert keys in addArticlePage.getDekContentUrlStripped()

        addArticlePage.loadUrl(addArticlePage.getPreviewUrl())
        articlePage = ArticlePage.ArticlePage(self.driver)
```

Another related [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003003/check-if-any-alert-exists-using-selenium-with-python)