# Selenium webdriver - Python - assert

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, assert

I am doing automatic test and i want to check the occurrence of an alert with the inscription "Good morning" (when i do assert). I am writing test in Python with selenium-webdriver. How should I do is to check?

Element:

```
<div class="alert alert-dismissable alert-info">
<button aria-hidden="true" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
Good morning
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003003/check-if-any-alert-exists-using-selenium-with-python

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.