# Wait until alert is not present - Selenium/Python

Tags: python, selenium

I found this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19019311/1998220 that waits until the alert is present, but I need the opposite so whoever runs the macro has time to authenticate on the proxy pop up. Is there an opposite to the below code?

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 60).until(EC.alert_is_present())
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can [wait for a specific URL, title, or a specific element to be present or visible](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html), but you can also have a specific `alert_is_not_present` *custom Expected Condition*:

```
class alert_is_not_present(object):
    """ Expect an alert to not to be present."""
    def __call__(self, driver):
        try:
            alert = driver.switch_to.alert
            alert.text
            return False
        except NoAlertPresentException:
            return True
```