# Python - Selenium - Close browser on alert

Tags: python, selenium

I'm using python3 + selenium to write a script.
Some of the pages I open request login:password with a popup alert. I want to escape that pages. So is there any way to close browser when this alert appears?
I tried to set the loading time limit but this doesn't work.

Comment: Please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003003/check-if-any-alert-exists-using-selenium-with-python ). Is it helpful ?

Comment: @Vimal I think you're right. Thanks.