# How can I click on alert pop up in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Hi can someone help me how can i accept the alert after I click the save button ?

[image]

I tried the accept.alert()  but its not working

[image]

Comment: this will help [Check if any alert exists using selenium with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003003/check-if-any-alert-exists-using-selenium-with-python)

Comment: im getting error "    alert = driver.switch_to.alert
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'switch_to'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this with explicitly wait condition:

```
alert = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    EC.alert_is_present())

alert.accept()
```

imports:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: im getting an error selenium.common.exceptions.NoAlertPresentException: Message: no such alert
  (Session info: chrome=89.0.4389.114)

Comment: yes it did.. i tried the driver wait too but its not working.. this is the site https://webapp.bailiwik.com/

Comment: how to add with alert?

Comment: if its okay I have another question in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67014419/how-to-click-on-item-in-ul-using-pythong-selenium?noredirect=1#comment118455749_67014419