# how to click on item in UL using pythong selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web

I want to click the 1st item, I tried locating it by using find element xpath, tag name,  but im getting an error

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: driver.find_element_by_class_name("woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link").click()

Comment: i use element from the line that its in highlight in the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you should realize, that selector what you're trying to interract with the page is not unique and class name is not enough to get the particular one

second I would suggest again using explicitly waits:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


timeout = 30
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://weed.com/product-category/cbd/')
element = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//a[@class='woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link'])[1]")))

element.click()

driver.quit()
```

if you want to click on the particular element, I would suggest using text and action-perform:

```
timeout = 30
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://weed.com/product-category/cbd/')

element = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//h2[text()='Binoid Good Night CBD Oil – Sleep Blend']")))

action = ActionChains(driver)

action.move_to_element(element).click().perform()

driver.quit()
```

Comment: im wondering how can i click the 1st item ?

Comment: @JHN in first construction, just add after elements[0].click()

Comment: @JHN webdriver is like find_element, and return elements or elements, but just wait before, really unique not get an exception not found element

Comment: @JHN my fault, i've skipped that you want to click on the first one and added like unique solution for all elements. so for the first one, check 1st code snipped, i've updated it for the first element

Comment: Awesome it works.. Now i 'll try the same thing in homepage ...

Comment: @JHN sure, advice to digger in xpath, explicity waits quite enough to interact with the page. if you have quesiton, free to ask)

Comment: yes for sure I appreciate your help.. if ever can I send pm here?.. I watched some youtube but when it comes to actual doing it's kinda tricky  :D

Comment: @JHN agree, it took some years for me to moving through it quite confidentially, but anyway always there's something new)

Comment: I know right... yeah ill poke you soon in case i have another question (which is for sure) :D

Comment: hey @Vova can I ask again? :D im trying to fill the expiry date in credit card info with format of MM/YY and my code is driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='authnet-card-expiry']").send_keys('0122') but I'm not getting my expected result its just display as 02/  ... in actual human interaction if I type on this field it automatically formatting my input