# Selenium python how to select element error window for assert order

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[image: How i find xpath for the messeage error up for testing]

I try all and didnt find how to get to the error messeage  thx for the help

Comment: This might help you [SO Archive link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003003/check-if-any-alert-exists-using-selenium-with-python)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like that is an alert.

You will have to **switch** to it before `extracting the text`.

```
try:
    time.sleep(2)
    Alert = driver.switch_to.alert
    print(Alert.text)
except:
    print('Could not interact with Alert')
    pass
```

Comment: You can assert like this `"assert "paste error message here" in Alert.text"`